How to get the touched event of an anchored part?
I've been making a tornado game in Roblox that requires a part to be the windfield of the tornado. Whenever the part is anchored, the touched event doesn't fire. Am i missing something? Is there a setting to fix this? Both are parts. If it is impossible for a touch event to be triggered on a anchored part, what are some workarounds? I've tried using a script to constantly update the part.Position.Y value to that of the part i want it to copy off; and i used this script:
while true do
      script.Parent.TornadoDamage.Position=Vector3.new(script.Parent.TornadoDamage.Position.X,script.Parent.Position.Y,script.Parent.TornadoDamage.Position.Z)

How can i use constraints, scripts or settings to keep the part from falling so I can use the touch event?

After grappling with this problem, I've figured out a solution. You can use the part:GetTouchingParts method and iterate through the list. Here's what I used for my game:
while true do
      wait(0.01)
      print("hi")
      for i,part in pairs(script.Parent:GetTouchingParts()) do
           if TornadoDamage.TornadoDamageKey(part,Debugging,5) then
                     TornadoDamage.TornadoPhysics(part,script.Parent,5,part.Parent)
          end
     end

end

